# How can I solve fatal compiler errors when installing GLScene into RAD Studio 2010?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, glscene

I'm trying to **install GLScene into RAD Studio 2010**, with the aim of using it from a mostly C++ project. I downloaded the [latest snapshot (5991, November 2011)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glscene/files/SVN%20Snapshots/) and have been trying to compile and install the two main packages:  `GLScene_DesignTime` and `GLScene_RunTime`. I haven't even tried some of the other libraries (CUDA, etc), I just want to get the base packages running.

I've encountered a number of problems, one of which I can't solve, and I'm seeking the help of anyone on SO who has **successfully installed GLScene**, or might know **how to solve these Delphi compiler errors.**

### First problem (solved?)

When compiling, a number of files gave the following error:

```
[DCC Warning] GLSelection.pas(297): W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'abstract class method'
```

This is caused by a method declaration something like:

```
TGLBaseSelectTechnique = class
  public
    class function IsSupported: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
```

It seems that a virtual abstract class method is not supported in Delphi 2010, and I have solved it by removing '`abstract`' and providing a dummy implementation, e.g. just returning `false`.

### The second problem (not solved) - Delphi compiler fatal errors

I am now encountering two more serious errors. When compiling, the compiler fails like so:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] Exception EAccessViolation: Access violation at address 05AE8ED9 in module 'dcc140.dll'. Read of address 00000003
[DCC Error] Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))
```

It doesn't say what file caused this, but I *think* it's caused by `Spline.pas`. Occasionally and not as often, I get this:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] Spline.pas(1): F2084 Internal Error: AV062D8ED9-R00000003-0
```

This indicates `Spline.pas`, and I think the first error is probably related to the file too, because after getting the first one if I then clean the project, cleaning will fail saying it could not delete `Spline.hpp`. (I have to close and reopen the IDE.) `Spline.hpp` just contains the following:

```
// CodeGear C++Builder
// Copyright (c) 1995, 2009 by Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
// All rights reserved

// (DO NOT EDIT: machine generated header) 'Spline.pas' rev: 21.00

#ifndef SplineHPP
#define SplineHPP

#pragma delphiheader begin
#pragma option push
#pragma option -w-      // All warnings off
#pragma option -Vx      // Zero-length empty class member functions
#pragma pack(push,8)
#include <System.hpp>   // Pascal unit
#include <Sysinit.hpp>  // Pascal unit
```

and there it stops.  It looks to me like it failed when trying to generate the HPP file.

**I always get one of these two failures.**  The second is the only one I can tie to a specific file; the first fails halfway through the project, but I can't see where it got up to when it failed.  I am compiling from inside the IDE.

I've looked in `Spline.pas`, and it seems pretty basic code - I can't see anything unusual at all. You can [find it here](http://glscene.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glscene/trunk/Source/Base/Spline.pas?revision=6065&view=markup), and apparently the file [hasn't been touched for seven years](http://glscene.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/glscene/trunk/Source/Base/)... so I think it should compile :)

If I change the project settings so it does not generate headers, it compiles fine. (Generating just obj files, and any other of the settings that does not include "headers", all work fine.) But this isn't a good workaround for me - after all, I need to use it from C++ Builder, so my normal setting would be "Generate all C++ Builder files". At a bare minimum, I need HPP and OBJ files.

Has anyone here used GLScene in a recent version of C++ Builder? Have you encountered similar problems? Any idea how to solve this one?

I am using:

- RAD Studio 2010 (fully patched and up to date; DDevExtensions and IDEFixPack installed.)
- The November 2011 snapshot; I tried the March 2011 snapshot too, and got the same problems.  [Link to snapshots here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glscene/files/SVN%20Snapshots/).
- The Delphi 2010 packages modified *only* by changing the linker output to generate C++ Builder files; and also the BCB 6 packages.  Both give the same errors.

Comment: If it's any consolation to you I get the exact same fatal error in Spline.pas  - Sounds like one for Embarcadero QC :-(

Comment: Thanks Roddy. Good to know, for certain definitions of good ;) I might see if it's possible to open a support case.  I'm worried just entering a QC won't achieve much.

Comment: Yeah, but NOT reporting it to QC is guaranteed to achieve even less!

Comment: Good point.  [Done.](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=105497)  Would you mind leaving a comment saying that you can reproduce this too, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** GLScene now has compatibility with RAD Studio XE3 (including C++ Builder.)

> Now there is full compatibility of GLScene with Embarcadero RAD Studio
>   C++Builder XE3 as in design and runtime mode.
>
> You can download it from http://yadi.sk/d/o1QGI2KA10MK1 (95Mb)

-- from [Pal Wassail's post on the Embarcadero forum thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=514233#514233).

---

> {quote:title=David M wrote:}{quote}
>   Hi,
>
> I'm trying to install GLScene into RAD Studio...
>   David

And here is more simple Test for EMB developers of Delphi XE3 header generator -

1.Create a VCL Form Application
2.Add in Unit1.pas interface section

```
type
 TVector3f = array[0..2] of single;
 TVector4f = array[0..3] of single;

 function VectorAdd(const v : TVector3f; const f : Single) : TVector3f; overload;
 function VectorAdd(const v : TVector4f; const f : Single) : TVector4f; overload;
```

3.Add in implementation section

```
function VectorAdd(const v : TVector3f; const f : Single) : TVector3f;
begin
  Result[0]:=v[0]+f;
  Result[1]:=v[1]+f;
  Result[2]:=v[2]+f;
end;

function VectorAdd(const v : TVector4f; const f : Single) : TVector4f;
begin
   Result[0]:=v[0]+f;
   Result[1]:=v[1]+f;
   Result[2]:=v[2]+f;
   Result[3]:=v[3]+f;
end;
```

1. Set Delphi Compiler option “Generate C++ .objs, headers, namespaces, export”
2. Build the project
3. Then Delphi XE3 compiler generates wrong header file Unit1.hpp with lines:

   extern PACKAGE TVector3f __fastcall VectorAdd
     (float const *v, const float f)/* overload   */;
   extern PACKAGE TVector4f __fastcall VectorAdd
     (float const *v, const float f)/* overload */;
4. If now you are trying to use this header file Unit1.hpp in my.cbproj you get fatal error:
   “E2238 Multiple declarations in …”

Yes, if you change vector array types to records:

```
 TVector3f = record
    case boolean of
      true  : (Coord: array[0..2] of single);
      false : (X,Y,Z: single);
end;
```

- then the problem could be solved, because in this case Delphi compiler generates

  extern PACKAGE Vectortypes::TVector3f __fastcall VectorAdd
     (const Vectortypes::TVector3f &v, const float f)/* overload */;
  extern PACKAGE Vectortypes::TVector4f __fastcall VectorAdd
     (const Vectortypes::TVector4f &v, const float f)/* overload */;

and you could build your C++Builder VCL application without "Multiple declaration " error. It was done for old GLScene version in 2007, but now you need to rewrite some part of code  in new library, starting from VectorGeometry.pas module.

1. There are second way to fix such automatic header's errors - improvement of Delphi compiler in Generating C/C++ headers, namespaces and packages option. But it's in hands of EMB developers.

Comment: Pal, I added a quote from your reply on the Embarcadero forum, and marked this answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Pal. I [reported](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/glscene/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4473&p=8625) about your patch to [official GLScene forum](https://sourceforge.net/apps/phpbb/glscene/viewforum.php?f=11), and  now your patch is applied to official GLScene repositry(https://sourceforge.net/projects/glscene/develop). see r6128-r6136. Could you please confirm SVN trunk version ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

- [Download and extract this ZIP file](http://www.simonjstuart.com/downloads/GLScenePkg_2007_XE2.zip) (directly into the root folder of GLScene, allowing it to overwrite as necessary)
- Load up the appropriate RAD Studio version (2007 to XE2) and open the file *GLScene_Group.groupproj* (where  = your RAD Studio version)
- Build/Install each Package in group order

I have carefully assembled these fixed packages to ensure they all install and function properly from 2007 to XE2. Some packages (at the bottom of each group) require additional dependencies to function (such as the Python package) so be mindful of these.

**I have tested and confirmed that these work on RAD Studio 2007 to XE2 only**.

Don't forget to add the *\Source* folder (and all subfolders) to the Search Paths (either for the IDE itself or an individual Project, as you desire) otherwise the projects using GLScene components will fail to compile complaining of missing units.

Enjoy!

Comment: Sounds very useful!  What did you do to create those packages that resulted in different results to mine?  That would be very useful information :)  Also, it's probably worth giving these to GLScene as a patch.

Comment: I simply loaded the DPK files with the correct versions of Delphi, modified the Search Paths so that all necessary Source files could be located, organized them into "installation order" within a group, tested them, zipped up the resulting files and put them online for you to enjoy :)

Comment: Well, thanks!  But that's pretty close to what I did... puzzling.  I'm glad yours work though :)

Comment: It's probably some seemingly-insignificant detail we did differently... not sure!

Answer (score 2):

Not for RAD Studio 2009 but for old GLScene installation in BCB6 she was running well.  But current version after installation in RAD Studio XE/XE2/XE3 does not work at all. It seems that the main problem is hidden in overload mechanism of procedures in Vectorgeometry.pas, so  Delphi compiler (with using an option for Output of all C++ files and packages) creates coincident strings in Vectorgeometry.hpp and others. Thus you have visual components in C++Builder panel, but your application fails with errors during building. It must be repaired in .pas files by GLScene developers.

When you trying to build an application with GLScene under C++Builder XE3 you will get  over 50 BCC32 errors in glcrossplatform.hpp, vectorgeometry.hpp and so on. There is a way to repair the library on your own discretion. Make a new copy of GLScene directory. In GLCrossPlatform.pas rename the procedure RGB to GLRGB (it's work!). Then in  VectorGeometry.pas and in many others files of source codes change all overload procedures with slightly different parameter names, so you should't encounter coincident procedures in .hpp files after Delphi option output C++ (last option that includes packages). Then rebuild all GLScene packages. At the end of the process I hope it should work for C++Builder XE3.

Answer (score 1):

I have exact he same errors.

@The second problem

Go to "spline.pas" and change

`TCubicSplineMatrix = array of array[0..3] of Single;`

to

`TCubicSplineMatrixEx = array[0..3] of Single;`

`TCubicSplineMatrix = array of TCubicSplineMatrixEx;`

Now "Rad Studio 2009" can compile and install GLScene for C++Builder. I can start a new C++Builder VCL Application and select GLScene components from the toolbox and drop in my VCL form.

I think, this is the solution for your basic problem, but unfortunately I can not compile my VCL project successful. I get over 50 BCC32 errors in glcrossplatform.hpp and vectorgeometry.hpp. If anyone can help here, that would be great.

@Your First problem

I get this warnings too, but I have nothing changed for it. Just ignore it?!

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  Maybe you could add your changes to the GLScene people so they can include them in their next release?